# Copying SQL Server Transaction Logs from Local Server to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, backup

I've Googled this a lot and can't really find anything.  The SQL Server for our main system is on-premise, not in the cloud.  I figured out how to copy our nightly SQL Server backup to Azure.  I also want to copy the Transaction Logs each time they roll so if our server dies we have the transaction logs, can restore to that point and only lose at most five minutes of work, not potentially a full day.

I'm really new to Azure, just starting to learn it.  Is there an easy way to copy the logs to Azure?  Can it be done within SSMS?  Does someone already have a script they'd be willing to share?  Thanks for any tips you might have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is [SQL Server Backup to Azure Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40740)

> Microsoft SQL Server Backup to Microsoft Azure Tool enables backup to
>   Azure Blob Storage and encrypts and compresses SQL Server backups
>   stored locally or in the cloud.

There's also Powershell option:

[Use PowerShell to Backup Multiple Databases to Windows Azure Blob Storage Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223322(v=sql.110).aspx)

> This topic provides sample scripts that can be used to automate backups to Windows Azure Blob storage service using PowerShell cmdlets. PowerShell support for Backup and Restore to Windows Azure Blob Storage service is introduced in SQL Server 2012 SP1 CU4.

The [parent article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919148(v=sql.110).aspx) gives you TSQL options as well.

Comment: Interesting.  So it doesn't leave a copy of the backup or log files on the local server.  This tool seems more like some Microsoft Garage experiment than a real tool because it doesn't have a l lot of instructions and doesn't seem very polished.  But it does do what I want.  Thanks, I'll play around with it. :)

Comment: I've added additional resources above as well, including powershell and TSQL options.